# Install VS 2008 and VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am using Windows 7 32-bit OS. I want to install Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010.

Please share any links which provides the free full version of these softwares.

Thanks a lot for your time..

Comment: http://www.google.com - "Visual Studio 2008 Express Download" and "Visual Studio 2010 Express Download". Google is a search engine. You can use it to find answers to your questions. Thank me later.

Comment: Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2008 Express in Windows 7?? I dint find Windows 7 in its supported OS list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you'll find all the steps explained once you buy the software packages. :)

But till then, you can download the [free Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express) as well.

I'm not sure if older versions are still available, but be careful if you're trying to download them from third party sites.

Comment: Is it possible to practice ASP .Net with WCF in the Visual Web Developer 2010 Express??

Comment: Never tried it, but I'd assume, because that should be the intended target for that edition.